# Error using pexpect and multiprocessing? error "TypError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object"

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, pexpect

I have a Python 3.7 script on a Linux machine where I am trying to run a function in multiple threads, but when I try I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 43, in <module>
    pt.ping_scanx()
  File "./test2.py", line 39, in ping_scanx
    par = Parallel(function=self.pingx, parameter_list=list, thread_limit=10)
  File "./test2.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._x = self._pool.starmap(function, parameter_list, chunksize=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 276, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

This is the sample code that I am using to demonstrate the issue:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pexpect   # Used to run SSH for sessions

class Parallel:

    def __init__(self, function, parameter_list, thread_limit=4):

        # Create new thread to hold our jobs
        self._pool = Pool(processes=thread_limit)

        self._x = self._pool.starmap(function, parameter_list, chunksize=1)

class PingTest():

    def __init__(self):
        self._pex = None

    def connect(self):
        self._pex = pexpect.spawn("ssh snorton@127.0.0.1")

    def pingx(self, target_ip, source_ip):
        print("PING {} {}".format(target_ip, source_ip))

    def ping_scanx(self):

        self.connect()

        list = [['8.8.8.8', '96.53.16.93'],
                ['8.8.8.8', '96.53.16.93']]

        par = Parallel(function=self.pingx, parameter_list=list, thread_limit=10)


pt = PingTest()
pt.ping_scanx()
```

If I don't include the line with pexpect.spawn, the error doesn't happen. Can someone explain why I am getting the error, and suggest a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `multiprocessing.Pool` you're actually calling the function as separate processes, not threads. Processes cannot share Python objects unless they are serialized first before transmitting them to each other via inter-processing communication channels, which is what `multiprocessing.Pool` does for you behind the scene using `pickle` as the serializer. Since `pexpect.spawn` opens a terminal device as a file-like `TextIOWrapper` object, and you're storing the returning object in the `PingTest` instance and then passing the bound method `self.pingx` to `Pool.starmap`, it will try to serialize `self`, which contains the `pexpect.spawn` object in the `_pex` attribute that unfortunately cannot be serialized because `TextIOWrapper` does not support serialization.

Since your function is I/O-bound, you should use threading instead via the [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy) module for more efficient parallelization and more importantly in this case, to allow the `pexpect.spawn` object to be shared across the threads, with no need for serialization.

Change:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

to:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/WiseYoungExperiments