# Independent python scripts sharing one queue

Tags: python, queue

I have multiple completely independent python scripts that log in to a customer network using SSH, do their thing, then return results in an email.

For security reasons, the access method to the network the scripts SSH to is changing to DUO. The scripts run at all kinds of different times and I can't be responding to DUO pushes at all hours of the day. So what I'd like to do is create a python queue that creates say 10 DUO sessions and keeps them up using keepalives.

Then, whenever one of the independent python scripts is launched via crontab, it would grab one of the sessions from the shared queue (which is always up), use it to do its thing, then puts it back on the queue. This way, I would only need to answer 10 DUO pushes when the python queue process is launched as well as if one of the sessions times out for any reason, which should be rarely.

Comment: What have you researched so far? Have you looked at [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)? It includes special multiprocessing queues: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes

Comment: Thanks Random. I wasn't aware of the "Server Process". I should have read the actual python docs instead of trying to google for an answer. My bad. Lesson learned.

Comment: Everything I've read so far assumes a parent process manages the queue and subprocesses access the queue. But in my case, all the processes are scripts that are independent from the parent process that has the queue. All I've been able to find so far that might help is pickling, which allows to save the queue to a file for other processes to access when needed. Not the best option, but since the queue will be small it might be the way to go.

Comment: i tried pickling a Queue containing pexpect.spawn sessions and it comes back with    TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object. So I'm still stuck. Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772451/error-using-pexpect-and-multiprocessing-error-typerror-cannot-serialize-io though which seems to explain the problem. Might have a way out.

Comment: @musca999 did you find any solution? I doubt if pickled Queue can help. i think unpickling creates another fresh copy of the pickled Queue